# perf.data file has no samples

Tags: profiling, perf

I am using perf 3.0.4 on ubuntu 11.10. Its record command works well and displays on terminal 256 samples collected. But when I make use of **perf report** , it gives me the following error:

```
perf.data file has no samples
```

I searched a lot for the solution but no success yet.

Comment: please give us the command your using to record events.

Comment: have you solved your issue ?

Comment: Just to give another reason the error might be happening: it might be [because events requested are not enabled in kernel](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207297#c1). Like for example, if you record one of `sched:` events, you gotta set `sudo sysctl kernel.sched_schedstats=1`.

Answer (score 19):

This thread has some useful information: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-perf-users/msg01436.html

It seems that if you are running in a VM that does not expose the PMU to the guest, the default collection (`-e cycles`) won't work. Try running with `-e cpu-clock`. According to that thread, the OP had the same problem also in a real host running Ubuntu 10.04, so it might solve it for you too...

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me troubleshoot an issue with flamegraphs (which rely on `perf`).  Hopefully my mentioning flamegraphs this comment will help others find this topic.

Comment: That did not help me, but thank you for pointing out the problem might be that it's running in the VM!

Answer (score 8):

Whenever I run into this on a machine where `perf record` has worked in the past, it is because I have left something else running that uses the performance counters, e.g., I have `perf top` running in another terminal tab.

In this case, it seems that `perf record` simply doesn't record any PMU related samples.

Answer (score 7):

The number of samples reported by the `perf record` command is an approximation and not the correct number of events ([see perf wiki here](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sampling_with_perf_record)).

To get the accurate number of events, dump the raw file and use `wc -l` to count then number of results:

> perf report -D -i perf.data | grep RECORD_SAMPLE | wc -l

This command should report 0 in your case where `perf report` says it can't find events.

Let us know more information about how you use perf record, which event are you sampling, which hardware, which program.

EDIT: you can try first to increase the sampling period or frequency with the `-c` or `-F` options